# Is there any software or web service that helps with the creation of Personas?

Tags: tools, personas

Totally new to this Persona thing, and I'm going to attempt creating one for the next project, still at the point of interviewing people to get the information needed to create a persona.

The question is if there's any software or service that would help the creation of personas, something that helps fit information for personas neatly, forms and such?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for tools or software rather than a UX question about personas.

Answer (score 2):

There are apps like [Mariner Persona](https://www.marinersoftware.com/products/persona/) that give you a form to fill out.

I've never used software like that though because they make you fill in stuff like height, weight and eye color, irrelevant things.

I normally create a scope of information relevant to the project I'm working on. Demographics, professions, hobbies, ethnicity, etc. Then I use a program like Adobe Indesign to set up a template for the persona's to be filled in later.

There are some helpful websites I find great however.
It's always hard to come up with the right pictures for your persona. [Uifaces](http://www.uifaces.com) helps with that. The same goes for making up names, [Uinames](http://www.uinames.com) is a fun tool that creates names for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you should remember about personas:

- **They are designed to generate *empathy* with the user.** They are poor user models (since they focus too much attention on single people), but they evoke a human response from people in the design team. They are tools for creating a good *user experience*.
- **They are meant for the whole team.** Personas are there to make sure that your programmers, your support staff and your project managers all feel empathy with the user, and start thinking about the user using the product. So they need to be distributed and to be permanently visibly throughout the company.

For these reasons, I would never use a specialized software tool to create Personas. First of all, you need to create personas with the whole team. Everybody needs to be involved in the process. If you just hand them down, nobody is going to care, but if you let the team make their own personas, they will remember them from day one.

Secondly, they need to look nice. Once you've done the work on paper with your team, create something unique that looks attractive: a poster that you can hang up among the developers, or a desktop background for your call center. If it looks automatically generated, people will ignore it. If it looks lovingly crafted, people will give you their attention. Make sure there's a human face on there.

So tailor them to your context, use nice big sheets of paper and big colorful marker pens when you're creating them with the team, and use generic design tools (InDesign, Photoshop) to create polished versions to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

Personas should be created using demographics of users who are going to be using your product. Basing them off of information gathered but surveying, information from Google Analytics, etc would be best.

http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/10/it-works-for-you-a-user-centric-guideline-to-product-pages/

If you are looking to how to create a persona in a more general sense, I'd recommend reading LEAN UX or referencing sites like AListApart.com to get an idea of how to create them and then use them effectively when vetting out your product.

Comment: For personas used for UX purposes (as opposed to marketing purposes), demographics-based personas aren't nearly as useful as behavior-based personas.  People from very different demographics often behave in similar ways when using software.

Comment: You still need to consider various demographic aspects of your target group. Older users versus younger users might respond to a UI design in various ways and if you're targeting a specific group of people, it should be taken into consideration. Not every UI element is universal across groups.

Comment: *Might* is the operative word here.  If there are demographic differences in how users behave, they should be captured in the personas.  Personas should reflect your target users and what they are trying to accomplish; your users aren't *just* their demographic.

Answer (score 0):

A persona is content more than anything. A word document is usually more than enough.